# Iceweasel on my Debian install won't follow some hyperlinks

Tags: firefox, browser, debian

I'm having some major issues with "Iceweasel" on Debian 6.0.1 (squeeze). I've done some extensive google searching but can't really find anything on this issue.

Basically, Iceweasel simply won't follow some links. It seems to spin for a second and then remain on the same page. I haven't been able to find any correlation between the type/style of links and whether or not the browser will work correctly or not when the link is clicked. Also, sometimes if I have multiple tabs open, I'll open gmail in a new tab and it will do nothing. If I exit the app and restart with one new tab, it will correctly bring up gmail (does this with other sites too gmail is just an example).

I actually use Chrome for most stuff now but need FF/Iceweasel for PHP debugging (a Zend Studio plugin not available in Chrome).

If anyone has a clue what this is, how to get more debug info form Iceweasel, or how to fix I'd greatly appreciate!

I've thought about just installing Firefox but seems I have to do it manually and I'm not convinced that it would make a difference as supposedly the code is the same (?). I may just try it anyway as I'm out of ideas.

Here's the stats:

```
peter@sendai[vanilla]$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-5-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-31) (ben@decadent.org.uk) (gcc version 4.3.5 (Debian 4.3.5-4) ) #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 21:35:22 UTC 2011

Iceweasel 3.5.16 (like Firefox 3.5.16)
```

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try GNU's Icecat, another fork of Firefox. I haven't had any issues clicking or not clicking on links with it, and it comes with a 'privacy extension' which may explain some of Iceweasel's behavior. Sadly, the privacy extension does not keep pace with Firefox and is marked incompatible.

There's a PPA for Ubuntu, so there has to be a Debian version lying around somewhere.